# I can't connect with CUPS

Tags: debian, cups

I installed CUPS following the Debian Wiki instructions with:

```
apt-get install cups-client cups-pdf cups
```

Then started the CUPS service, `/etc/init.d/cups start`, and then tried connecting to `http://localhost:631/`, but `firefox` or `w3m` can't connect with it.

When I run `/etc/init.d/cups status`, the answer is:

> Status of Common Unix Printing System: cupsd is running.

My OS is Debian Wheezy.

Edited: Added output of logs and some commands

Output from `netstat -lntp`:

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1834/rpcbind    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48240           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1868/rpc.statd  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2564/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3206/exim4      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1834/rpcbind    
tcp6       0      0 :::44155                :::*                    LISTEN      1868/rpc.statd
```

Output from `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
E [25/Sep/2013:00:07:12 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:00:11:42 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:00:11:42 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:00:34:43 +0200] Avahi client failed, closing client to allow a clean restart
E [25/Sep/2013:08:09:21 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:10:34:11 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:10:47:41 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:16:20:49 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:16:53:56 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address [v1.::1]:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
E [25/Sep/2013:16:53:56 +0200] Unable to bind socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address.
```

Output from `/var/log/cups/access_log`:

```
localhost - - [25/Sep/2013:00:07:15 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3498492 CUPS-Get-PPDs -
```

`iptables-save` has no output.

Comment: Please append the output of `netstat -lntp` and `iptables-save` to your posting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the `/var/log/cups` directory. There are typically 3 files there that CUPS uses to log messages:

- access_log
- error_log
- page_log

#### Examples

Accessing this directory will require `sudo`. You can do so like this:

```
$ sudo head -5 access_log error_log page_log
==> access_log <==
localhost - ethan [24/Sep/2013:07:39:57 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - ethan [24/Sep/2013:07:53:57 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - ethan [24/Sep/2013:08:07:57 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - ethan [24/Sep/2013:08:21:57 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - ethan [24/Sep/2013:08:35:57 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription successful-ok

==> error_log <==
E [24/Sep/2013:07:38:40 -0400] Unknown directive SystemGroup on line 16 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
W [24/Sep/2013:07:38:40 -0400] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Brother-MFC-8480DN-Gray..' already exists
W [24/Sep/2013:07:38:40 -0400] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Brother-MFC-8480DN' already exists

==> page_log <==
```

#### Your issue

You should see access when you attempt to browse to `http://localhost:631` in the `access_log`.